# Onecolum at the end in twocolum

Tags: tables, page-breaking, two-column

So I have two problems:
first. how to add onecolumn at the end of article withtout breaking page?
second. same but after table in the middle of text? [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could push a box into position using some "magic":

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{balance}% http://ctan.org/pkg/balance
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]\balance

\leavevmode\hfill\smash{\raisebox{-10\baselineskip}{\llap{%
  \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
    \lipsum[1]%
  }}}}%
}
\end{document}​
```

The above mixture of commands pushes a `\parbox` (that fits exactly within the text block horizontally) down 10 lines ("raised" `-10\baselineskip`s) from the right margin (as pushed over by `\leavevmode\hfill`). The box has zero width according to TeX since it's inside a `l`eft over`lap` and is `\smash`ed.

To have the box start at length `2<x>` from the left, centred, use

\leavevmode\hfill\smash{\raisebox{-10\baselineskip}{\llap{%
  \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-}{%
    %
  }}\hspace*{.5}}}%
}

For example, starting at `.25\columnwidth` from the left, one would use

```
\leavevmode\hfill\smash{\raisebox{-10\baselineskip}{\llap{%
  \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule-.5\columnwidth}{%
    \lipsum[1]%
  }}\hspace*{.25\columnwidth}}}%
}
```

[image]

Note that this will only be viable if there's enough space left at the bottom of the page, otherwise it could flow into the page footer.

Answer (score 7):

Both your problems can be easily solved using the [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package; you simply end the `multicols` environment, typeset one-column material and then start a new `multicols` environment. A little example (warning: floating environments cannot be placed inside the `multicols` environment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1-11]
\end{multicols}
{\centering\fbox{\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\lipsum[2]}}\par}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}
{\centering\fbox{\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\lipsum[2]}}\par}

\end{document}
```

And an image of the relevant page:

[image]

If using, the `multicol` package is not an option, for your first problem, you can use [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/TikZ):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
  \node[yshift=6cm] at (current page.south) 
    {\fbox{\parbox{.7\textwidth}{\lipsum[2]}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

A fragment of the last page obtained:

[image]

The [`eso-pic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) or [`textpos`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos) packages can also provide solutions.

Unfortunately now, for the second problem, things are not simple: an option would be to use the `figure*` or `table*` environments to place material spanning both columns, but those environments always place their contents in the top of the following page page. Using `\onecolumn` is not an option for you since it starts a new page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the package [`multicol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/multicol/)

Comment: I can not use multicols because I use balance.

Comment: But multicols balances the columns by default (it can be turned off).